# ERROR if do we not insert a PK auto inc decimal ID

Tags: c#, linq, sql-insert

Older dB has 3 related ID's that are decimals for some unknown reason that can't be changed to INT. Using the old entityspace we did not have to insert a ID. The new code uses LINQ and if we don't look for the last ID then insert it with the other data we get an error upon insert. So for now we need to get and insert the next id (horrible, yes).

```
[Id] (PK, numeric(18,0) not null)
```

I checked to make sure that dataclasses matched the INT's that we do not    need to insert

This works:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_BalanceId",   
       AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", 
       IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
```

This doesn't work:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id",     
       AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, 
       DbType="Decimal(18,0) NOT NULL IDENTITY", 
       IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
```

We cannot change the Id to an `INT` :)

My friend made this to insert the Id but it is ridiculously slow for 50,000 inserts.

```
    var campaign = new Campaign
    {
        Id = subFactory.CampaignNewId(),
        UserId = userId,
        User = user.SystemUser,
        MessageId = whatMsgid == 0 ? (int?)null : whatMsgid,
        VMMessageId = whatMsgVmailid == 0 ? (int?)null : whatMsgVmailid,
        PriorityId = priorityOfcalls,
        TTSDataFileId = null,
```

Here is the method:

```
 public int CampaignNewId()
 {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Context.Campaigns.Max(p=>p.Id)) + 1;
 }
```

Lost on this one. The programmer blames the poor dB design and of course the DBA blames the programmer for doing it wrong.

Comment: You described the problem very clearly, but what is the question? :)

Comment: The problem is that we should not have to insert the Id. in the insert statement. We never had to with enityspaces and it was instant. We want it to work like before:
            

      var campaign = new Campaign
                    {
                      // Nothing here
                        UserId = userId,
                        User = user.SystemUser,
                        MessageId = whatMsgid == 0 ? (int?)null : whatMsgid,
                        VMMessageId = whatMsgVmailid == 0 ? (int?)null : whatMsgVmailid,
                        PriorityId = priorityOfcalls,

Comment: Edit that comment into your question and formulate it into a question, then it is clear to all reading it.

Comment: We have to loop thought many tables to create a job and it use to take 1 second now takes 7 minutes with all of the lookups for the next available id  :(

Comment: Well from the looks of the code, you are cycling to get the next id on each insert which will be very slow.  Why dont you do this first `Convert.ToInt32(Context.Campaigns.Max(p=>p.Id)) + 1;` and save it on the side. then increment from that number instead of doing it each time you insert?

Comment: How can we NOT insert the Id in the insert statement above?
            

             var campaign = new Campaign
                    {
                      // WE WANT TO NOT INSERT THE ID HERE
                        UserId = userId,
                        User = user.SystemUser,

Comment: @imGreg  We thought of that but if another user inserts at the same time we will have a conflict. We want to use the auto increment as before.

Comment: what framework are you using to do your sql calls? EF?

Comment: @imGreg - if you can think of another way please let me know.

Comment: Just linq, we do not use EnitySpaces anymore.

Comment: @ThomasMahoney so are you using plain oledb to do your calls ?

Comment: Also, you will still have a conflict with the above code, The moment you get the max value it could have changed already by another user.

Comment: Best thing you can do is get the ID in the Script by doing a `SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;` if youre using SQL

Comment: Yes, default Ole and we should not have to set the Id as it is set as an primary key.

Comment: You say "older DB", did you change which database engine is hosting your data, or only the framework used to talk to it?

Comment: Also, which database engine and version are you using to actually host your data? Since you say "IDENTITY" I'm assuming some version of SQL Server, but if so, then which version specifically?

Comment: What happens if you ommit DbType in that attribute?

Comment: we host our own SQL server and nothing has changed. half of our code still uses the enityspaces Lib and all works on same dB. There should be a way to force LINQ to insert all data without requiring an insert of an  Id.

Comment: Looks like the best solution is to use a stored procedure to make your inserts, if needed the stored procedure can return the ID you have calculated  and update your object...

Comment: What error are you actually getting? What version of SQL are you using? I just made a little test project and I was able to define the PK as an auto-incrementing numeric column.

Comment: @BerndLinde thanks,   We are using SQL2008R2 and you are correct, that it works with enitySpaces without inserting an Id and for some reason it does not work with plane old Linq project,  So I think that I need to change some setting in the project. I like the idea of a SP if we can't figure out why the simple insert needs the Id inserted,

Comment: My test was with plain LINQ2Sql. What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: What error do you get with `Decimal(18,0) NOT NULL IDENTITY`?  And Decimal(18,0) is definitely a strange choice.  BigInt has a wider range takes 8 bytes.  Decimal(19,0) has a wider range and takes 9 bytes.  Decimal(18,0) takes 9 bytes.  So it has a smaller range than both, and takes more storage space than BigInt and same space as Decimal(19,0).

Comment: Error is gone. Thanks to everyone. I had error in the class I found based on @BerndLinde Linde sample project I started looking at something else. Thanks so much everyone for fixing this with your suggestions of what to look for.